# Javascript 'in' operator inside for loop returns type error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, typeerror, in-operator

Why does javascript return this type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'active' in undefined
```

when I do something like this

```
foo = [ 
          {link:"http1", active:"true"}, 
          {link:"http2", active:"true"}, 
          {link:"http3"}  
      ]

    var checker = function(){

        for(i=0; i<= foo.length; i++){ 
            if('active' in foo[i]){
                checked = true
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I do this in the console with the same foo object

```
'active' in foo[0]
```

it returns true?

Comment: JavaScript best practice: don't use `in`. JavaScript has supported what you're trying to do since forever as simply `if (foo[i].active) { ... }`, or if the property is in a named variable, let's pretend we have one call "propname", `if (foo[i][propname]) { ... }`. And for sanity, you do `if (foo[i] && foo[i].active) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you. Coming from python it seems normal to do 'in' but I see what you're saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says the expression `foo[i]` is undefined - because, the expression *does* evaluate to undefined. (Hint: i = 4).

Trivially the issue is reproducible with `'active' in undefined`, no loop required.

The cause in this case is an incorrect condition for the loop: it should be `i < foo.length`, so `i` goes 0..3 and not 0..4.

The code should likely also use a local `i` (thanks RobG!), a `break` (when checked is set), return a value from the function (instead of using a presumed global), and/or be replaced with [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Now also closing as "a typographical error"..

Comment: Ahhh dang didn't catch that. Yup makes sense, I should have checked to make sure the checked value was true first.

Comment: Consider keeping variables local, especially counters: `for (var i=0, iLen=foo.length, checked=false; i<iLen && !checked; i++) {checked = !!foo[i] && 'active' in foo[i]}` or something like that.